# Saving Excel workbook as PDF gives me an OLE error 800A03EC

Tags: excel, delphi, automation, ole

I have the following function that I want to use for creating a PDF from Excel.
But when trying to save the PDF I get an OLE error 800A03EC that I simply can't figure out.
I use the same approach to create PDF from Word and that works just fine.

```
function xlsCreatePdf(aInput: string; aOutput: string = ''): string;
var
  FileDoc: OleVariant;
  FilePDF: OleVariant;
  ExcelBook: ExcelWorkbook;
  PdfName: string;
  ExcelApp: ExcelApplication;
begin
  Result := '';
  if aOutput = '' then
    begin
      PdfName := Folders.DirOutput + ExtractFileName(aInput);
      PdfName := ChangeFileExt(PdfName, '.pdf');
    end
  else
    PdfName := aOutput;

  if (Files.Validate(aInput)) then
    begin
      if not Assigned(ExcelApp) then
        ExcelApp := xlsInitialize;
      FileDoc := aInput;
      ExcelBook := ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(FileDoc,
                                           EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
                                           EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
                                           EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
                                           EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
                                           EmptyParam, EmptyParam, DefaultLCID);
      FilePdf := PdfName;
      ExcelBook.SaveAs(FilePdf, xlTypePDF,
                       EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
                       False, False,
                       xlNoChange, xlUserResolution, False,
                       EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, DefaultLCID);
      xlsFreeAndNil(ExcelApp);

      if (Files.Validate(PdfName)) then
        Result := PdfName
      else
        Result := '';
    end;
end;
```

I initialize Excel using

```
function xlsInitialize: ExcelApplication;
var
  ExcelApp: ExcelApplication;
begin
  DefaultLCID := LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT;
  ExcelApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application') as ExcelApplication;
  if Assigned(ExcelApp) then
    begin
      Result := ExcelApp;
      ExcelApp.Visible[DefaultLCID] := True;
    end
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Cannot initialize Excel application');
end;
```

And it should be closed using

```
procedure xlsFreeAndNil(var ExcelApp: ExcelApplication);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  if Assigned(ExcelApp) then
    begin
      for i := 0 to ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Count - 1 do
        ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Close(DefaultLCID);
      ExcelApp.Quit;
      Pointer(ExcelApp) := Nil;
    end;
end;
```

I am using Delphi XE7 and Excel 2010 - the Office TLB used is 2010

Comment: so. where exactly do you get an exception?

Comment: and check your `xlsFreeAndNil` proc, which has a for-loop but doesn't use for-loop variable in it.

Comment: The error comes with 'ExcelBook.SaveAs'

Comment: That for loop was a left over from earlier attempts - it is gone now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t think that converting to PDF would be a normal SaveAs.
You should try exporting it, [as said here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198122.aspx)

Comment: - My bad for overlooking that. Or M$' bad for not making it work alike in Word and Excel :-)  But it works like you say and that is the important thing.